# How do I get value of jQuery slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried to get the value of the slider 'red' like:

```
red : $('#red').slider('value'),
```

but it doesn't work. Anybody can tell me why? I am trying to create a color picker using jQuery slider.

```js
var canvas2D = {
  canvas : undefined,
  canvasContext : undefined,
  x : undefined,
  y : undefined,
  w : undefined,
  h : undefined,
  color : undefined,
  red : $('#red').slider('value'),
  green : $('#green').slider('value'),
  blue : $('#blue').slider('value')
};

canvas2D.start = function()
{
  canvas2D.canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  canvas2D.canvasContext = canvas2D.canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas2D.w = 100;
  canvas2D.h = 50;
  canvas2D.x = canvas2D.canvas.width/2;
  canvas2D.y = canvas2D.canvas.height/2;
  canvas2D.color = "rgb(" + canvas2D.red + ", " + canvas2D.green + ", " + canvas2D.blue+ ")";
  canvas2D.draw();
};

canvas2D.draw = function() 
{
  canvas2D.canvasContext.fillStyle = canvas2D.color;
  canvas2D.canvasContext.fillRect(canvas2D.x - canvas2D.w/2,canvas2D.y - canvas2D.h/2,canvas2D.w,canvas2D.h);
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Color Picker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas width="800" height="600" id="canvas"></canvas><br>
  <label for="red">Red:</label>
  <input type="range" name="red" id="red" value="60" min="0" max="255" >
  <label for="green">Green:</label>
  <input type="range" name="green" id="green" value="60" min="0" max="255" >
  <label for="blue">Blue:</label>
  <input type="range" name="blue" id="blue" value="60" min="0" max="255">
  <script>canvas2D.start();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's `$.slider()`? I don't think that's a part of jquery-mobile. Your demo doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can get the value of input type=range using

Jquery

`$('#red').val();`

Javascript

```
document.getElementById('#red').value
```

$('#red').slider('value');  is the method for the the https://jqueryui.com/ slider component . I don' see that being included or used in your code.